# Sequential transforming XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am facing an issue during transformation and need your help regarding the same.
My XML:

```
<Root>
<ActualXML>
        <Node>  
            <a>a1</a>                               
            <b>b1</b>               
            <ChildNode1>    
                <c>c1</c>                               
                <d>d1</d>       
                <e>e1</e>                                   
            </ChildNode1>   
            <ChildNode2>                    
                <m>m1</m>                                       
                <n>n1</n>                                       
                <o>o1</o>                                               
            </ChildNode2>           
        </Node>
        <Node>              
            <a>a2</a>                               
            <b>b2</b>                       
            <ChildNode1>
                <c>c2</c>
                <d>d2</d>                                           
            </ChildNode1>               
        </Node>
</ActualXML>
<ReferenceXML>
   <Node>
        <a sample="    "/>
        <b sample="        "/>
        <p sample="    "/>
        <q sample="    "/>
   </Node>
   <ChildNode1>
        <c sample="            "/>
        <d sample="        "/>
        <e sample=" "/>
        <f sample=" "/>
   </ChildNode1>
   <ChildNode2>
        <l sample="            "/>
        <m sample="    "/>
        <n sample="    "/>
        <o sample="        "/>
   </ChildNode2>
</ReferenceXML>
</Root>
```

From this XML I have to perform 2 things:

1. Format Actual XML as per Reference XML. Adding spaces to string length as per standard reference defined.-This is acheived
2. **Maintain sequence from Actaul XML for Parent-Child-Parent.**

My current output sequence is: Node-Node-ChildNode1-Childnode-1-Childnode2

My desired output sequence is: Node-ChildNode1-Childnode2-Node-ChildNode1

Current XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="replacements" select="Root/ActualXML"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Root/ActualXML">
            <!--xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/-->
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ReferenceXML">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ReferenceXML/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//ReferenceXML/Node">
    <xsl:call-template name="selectsNode">
        <xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count(/Root/ActualXML/Node)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="selectsNode">
    <xsl:param name="i" />
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
        <Node>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//ReferenceXML/Node/*" >
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$i"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Node>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
        <xsl:call-template name="selectsNode">
            <xsl:with-param name="i">
                <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//ReferenceXML/Node/*">
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:variable name="replacement" 
       select="$replacements/Node[position()=$count]/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($replacement | current()[not($replacement)],@sample),1,string-length(@sample))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//ReferenceXML/ChildNode1">
    <xsl:call-template name="selectsChildNode1">
        <xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count(/Root/ActualXML/Node/ChildNode1)"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="selectsChildNode1">
    <xsl:param name="i" />
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
        <ChildNode1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//ReferenceXML/ChildNode1/*" >
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$i"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ChildNode1>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
        <xsl:call-template name="selectsChildNode1">
            <xsl:with-param name="i">
                <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>  <xsl:template match="//ReferenceXML/ChildNode1/*">
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:variable name="replacement" 
       select="$replacements/Node[position()=$count]/ChildNode1/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($replacement | current()[not($replacement)],@sample),1,string-length(@sample))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//ReferenceXML/ChildNode2/*">
    <xsl:variable name="replacement" 
       select="$replacements/Node/ChildNode2/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($replacement | current()[not($replacement)],@sample),1,string-length(@sample))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current o/p xml:

```
<Root>
<ActualXML>
    <Node>  
        <a>a1  </a>                               
        <b>b1      </b>  
        <p>    </p>
        <q>    </q>
    </Node>     
    <Node>              
        <a>a2    </a>                               
        <b>b2      </b> 
        <p>    </p>
        <q>    </q>
    </Node>         
    <ChildNode1>    
            <c>c1          </c>                               
            <d>d1      </d>       
            <e>1</e>     
            <f> </f>
    </ChildNode1>                       
    <ChildNode1>
            <c>c2          </c>
            <d>d2      </d>     
            <e> </e>     
            <f> </f>                                           
    </ChildNode1>  
    <ChildNode2>    
            <l>            </l>
            <m>m1  </m>                                       
            <n>n1  </n>                                       
            <o>o1      </o>                                               
    </ChildNode2>  
</ActualXML>
</Root>
```

Desired o/p xml:
I need help only while managing sequences.

```
<Root>
<ActualXML>
    <Node>  
        <a>a1  </a>                               
        <b>b1      </b>  
        <p>    </p>
        <q>    </q>
    </Node>          
    <ChildNode1>    
            <c>c1          </c>                               
            <d>d1      </d>       
            <e>1</e>     
            <f> </f>
    </ChildNode1>   
    <ChildNode2>    
            <l>            </l>
            <m>m1  </m>                                       
            <n>n1  </n>                                       
            <o>o1      </o>                                               
    </ChildNode2>      
    <Node>              
        <a>a2    </a>                               
        <b>b2      </b> 
        <p>    </p>
        <q>    </q>
    </Node>                      
    <ChildNode1>
            <c>c2          </c>
            <d>d2      </d>     
            <e> </e>     
            <f> </f>                                           
    </ChildNode1>
</ActualXML>
</Root>
```

Comment: Can you add the desired output structure to the question?

Comment: Hello Aniket, I have added the desired o/p xml above.

Comment: This coding style looks so bad. Why dont you just make normal apply-templates, so the order doesn't change? If im right your xml just puts the child nodes one level higher and applies the spaces? If thats the case I can post you the refactored solution. Im bit to lazy to read all your code now.

Comment: Hello Christian, Along with adding spaces, it also adds nodes from ReferenceXML which are missing in actualXML. This was reason I decided to match reference xml template. But now it is fails for sequencing in case where actual xml child node has further child nodes. It is a big XML file in real which I have reduced a lot for posting.